# iOS 7 HTML5 Video Tag Frame Size

Tags: ios, html, cordova, ios7, html5-video

I have used HTML5 video tag in iOS PhoneGap application to play the MP4 files. The URLs are perfectly fine and the video plays normally on iOS6.

But when I switch to iOS7 - I find that the video frame size is too large that it should be. The video seems to be zoomed in. Below is the screenshot of the same. If I could get any help from HTML5 developers :)

[image]